# Automating Google Soccer 2012

Tags: canvas, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to automate [Google Soccer 2012](https://www.google.com/doodles/soccer-2012), just for fun. I did not have any problems [automating other Google games](http://filipin.eu/tag/game/).

The problem with Soccer is that it does not react to `left` and `right`, but `space` works just fine.

This is the entire script:

```
puts "Go to game."
require "bundler/setup"
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto "https://www.google.com/doodles/soccer-2012"

sleep 1
puts "Go!"
browser.div(id: "hplogo").frame.div.click

sleep 1
puts "Left!"
browser.send_keys :left

sleep 1
puts "Rigth!"
browser.send_keys :right

sleep 1
puts "Space!"
browser.send_keys :space
```

You can see code for Soccer and other games at https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/olympics

Anybody has an idea how to get `left` and `right` working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goalie kind of moves a little if you hit the arrow key many times:

```
100.times{browser.send_keys :left}
```

Which makes me think that you need to some how hold down the arrow key rather than just tapping it. Unfortunately I could not find a way to hold keys down (the selenium-webdriver action builder key_down seems to only allow control keys).

If you are okay with not using the keyboard, the goalie seems to respond well to the mouse:

```
def move(browser, direction)
    el = browser.driver.find_element(:id, 'hplogo')
    case direction
        when :start
            browser.driver.action.move_to(el).perform
        when :left
            browser.driver.action.move_by(-1, 0).perform
        when :left_fast
            browser.driver.action.move_by(-5, 0).perform            
        when :right
            browser.driver.action.move_by(1, 0).perform
        when :right_fast
            browser.driver.action.move_by(5, 0).perform         
        when :jump
            browser.send_keys :space
    end
end

puts "Go to game."
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto "https://www.google.com/doodles/soccer-2012"

sleep 1
puts "Go!"
browser.div(id: "hplogo").frame.div.click
move(browser, :start) #Centre mouse

sleep 1
puts "Left!"
80.times{move(browser, :left)}

sleep 1
puts "Right!"
10.times{move(browser, :right_fast)}

sleep 1
puts "Space!"
move(browser, :jump)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sleep 3
puts "Left!"
browser.send_keys :left
```

you send the left and right keys too quickly. The animation doesn't seem to detect the input untill the animation has finished.

Comment: I do not think that is the problem. I have tried sending left/right from IRB after waiting for 10-20 seconds, it did not work. Does sending left/right work for you when you increase sleeps?

Comment: yes it does... when I had it on 1 didn't work, on 3 worked. :/

Comment: No, still does not work for me. Can you let me know your ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver and chromedriver versions? (I have all the latest, on windows 7.)

Comment: it seems to be hit and miss as went back to it after it worked and it doesn't always work. But yes, Ubuntu 12.04,  ruby 1.9.3p194, latest version of watir-webdriver 0.6.1 and 2.25.0 of selenium. Chrome driver is the latest for 64 bit linux